# Is there a difference between "select of your own choosing [something]" and "select [something] of your own choosing"?

Tags: word-choice, semantics

What is the semantic difference between "select of your own choosing a partner" and "select a partner of your own choosing"? Slightly awkward grammar aside, the first seems to suggest that the choice is whether or not to participate in the selection process, while the second seems to suggest that the choice is of the partner, but is there any real difference between these two wordings?

Comment: The title of your question seems to be asking about which of two different phrases to use, yet the body is concerned about the *location* of only the first phrase and doesn't mention the second (which should actually be "of your *own* choice". Can you clarify what your exact intentions are?

Comment: Tried to be a little more clear.

Answer (score 2):

The first form sounds decidedly odd to me, but I can't see it meaning anything different to the second.

They both seem tautological anyway. *Select* means *choose*; I don't see the point in saying *Choose a partner of your own choosing*. I think just *Choose a partner* is simpler and better.

To convey that even making a choice is optional, say *You may choose a partner [if you wish]*